# How to fix squarespace H1 empty tag

Tags: html, css, seo, squarespace, page-title

For some reason squarespace only allows you to choose a title on your page or an image logo (not both), right now I'm using the company logo but on my SEO I get an empty H1 tag which makes sense since squarespace renders it as:

```
<h1 id="logoImage" class="tmpl-loading logo-image"><a href="/"><img src="//static1.squarespace.com/static/52fe4d7be4b029ff09165036/t/57e0298ed1758e6d441ad15c/1493665228848/?format=1500w" alt="Am-Finn Sauna and Steam"></a></h1>
```

- Has anyone have found a roundabout for this? Is it possible to have both?

Answer (score 1):

After several testing what I did is use the title without the logo and via css I created a background-image with the actual logo, making the title opacity to 0.
 -It solves my H1 empty tag problem.